# setTimeout in React re-render 2 times every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like create an setTimeout in my React Component, but the setTimeout is render 2 times every second. I don't understand why (:

My component code :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.clearTimeout();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.clearTimeout();
  }

  clearTimeout = () => {
    window.clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.setState({ timer: 0 });
  }

runCounter() {
    const { timer, duration, max_duration } = this.state;
    const offset = 5;
    const startDuration = offset;
    const endDuration = parseInt(duration) + offset;

    let startMaxDuration;
    let endMaxDuration;

    if (!max_duration) {
      startMaxDuration = (this.props.store.get('session').maxdurationDefault *60) - 10 + offset;
      endMaxDuration = startMaxDuration + 10;
    } else {
      startMaxDuration = max_duration - 10 + offset;
      endMaxDuration = startMaxDuration + 10;
    }

    this.timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ timer: timer + 1 });

      console.log(this.state.timer); // 2 times re-render

      switch (this.state.timer) {
        case startDuration:
          this.startDuration();
          break;
        case endDuration:
          this.endDuration();
          break;
        case startMaxDuration:
          this.startMaxDuration();
          break;
        case endMaxDuration:
          this.endMaxDuration();
          return false;
          break;
      }

      this.runCounter();
    }, 1000);

  }

  render() {
    <div>
        {showStartCounter &&
          <Counter begin={5} end={0} className="is-absolute" />
        }
        {showQuestionCounter &&
          <Counter begin={0} end={duration} maxDuration={max_duration} className="is-offset" />
        }
        {showQuestionMaxDuration &&
          <Counter begin={10} end={0} maxDuration={max_duration} className="is-absolute" />
        }
    </div>
  }
```

I run my `runCounter` method on click event.

Anyone have idea why my setTimeout is rerender 2 times every second ? I don't undestand where is the problem :)

Thank you community!

Comment: Post your complete component so we can figure out what's wrong. Where is the `render` method ?

Comment: Plop ! I've add my `render` method, just show simple Counter component (only graphic)

Comment: I don't understand your render method. Doesn't it crash as the render method doesn't `return` anything ?

Comment: Isn't `runCounter` recursive? It's being called within itself.

Comment: Where have you defined showStartCounter, showQuestionCounter  and showQuestionMaxDuration?